Apache 2.0 API, GPL 3.0 Server side source code
I'm working in the with the OpenRouteService project to develop a specific custom routing method for a project. I don't include the library itself in my application (although I might include the api if I later package this into a standalone app). However, the OpenRouteService server side routing code is GPL 3.0 licensed.
I don't plan on including any code, or even a link to any server side code within my project. However, the api is obviously dependent on the existence a server running this code, or at minimum accepting api calls with the format defined by the OpenRouteService server. I could, as far as my client app is concerned, theoretically set up the server to accept these calls using a different service.
So, is my source code restricted by the apache or the GPL3.0 license?

Yes, your source code is restricted by Apache-2.0 and GPL-3.0 but not in the sense you might be thinking of.
If your use-over-network-only server uses a GPL-3.0 licensed code you have to comply with the GPL-3.0 requirements but those do not include the necessity to publish the source code. If it was licensed under AGPl-3.0 you would have to publish the source code.
If your client uses Apache-2.0 licensed code then you have to note all the major modifications and comply with the other requirements of the Apache-2.0.
